# Confusion with list-style<li>

Tags: css, xhtml

I have a problem with `li`, when I take `li` in `inline` display with `list-style`  (bullet-point ), then bullet-points don't show.

Comment: what you mean (bullet-point)? there is no property in CSS called bullet point http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-type.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need crossbrowser compatibility

Here are 2 methods

1. Use images `li {background-image:url(bullet.gif) no-repeat center left;padding-left:20px;display:inline;}`
2. or use `&bull;` like this  `<li>&bull; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>`

Comment: "...compatibility without" - what? :) And while you're at it, perhaps it ought to be spelled "methods", not "mrthods".

Answer (score 7):

`bullet-point` is *not* a valid value for `list-style`. Instead, use [one of these](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-type.asp):

- **none**  No marker
- **circle**    The marker is a circle
- **disc**  The marker is a filled circle. This is default
- **square**    The marker is a square
- **armenian**  The marker is traditional Armenian numbering
- **decimal**   The marker is a number
- **decimal-leading-zero**  The marker is a number padded by initial zeros (01, 02, 03, etc.)
- **georgian**  The marker is traditional Georgian numbering (an, ban, gan, etc.)
- **lower-alpha**   The marker is lower-alpha (a, b, c, d, e, etc.)
- **lower-greek**   The marker is lower-greek (alpha, beta, gamma, etc.)
- **lower-latin**   The marker is lower-latin (a, b, c, d, e, etc.)
- **lower-roman**   The marker is lower-roman (i, ii, iii, iv, v, etc.)
- **upper-alpha**   The marker is upper-alpha (A, B, C, D, E, etc.)
- **upper-latin**   The marker is upper-latin (A, B, C, D, E, etc.)
- **upper-roman**   The marker is upper-roman (I, II, III, IV, V, etc.)
- **inherit**   Specifies that the value of the list-style-type property should be inherited from the parent element

[Click through](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_list-style-type.asp) to read more about this, including browser support

Comment: I don't think this is what shivlal was asking. Notice the "`inline` display" in the question.

Comment: If an LI's display is set to inline, it will still have a bullet unless the list-style is busted. If poster is trying to throw <li> tags anywhere, not just within a UL or OL...that's an entirely different question...

Answer (score 5):

The list bullets show up because `<li>` elements have `display: list-item` by default. If you change it to anything else (e.g., `display: inline` or even `display: block`), the bullets are gone.

If you want to accomplish horizontal menus, you have two possibilities:

1. Leave the default `display` attribute and play with `float` instead
2. Simulate bullets with background images

Comment: This is great to remember for DEstyling list items. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i think you'd have to use float if you want to show the list items flowed and not as block plus see the bullets

Answer (score 0):

Do you have margins/padding set for the ul or li's?  Do you have a browser reset in your stylesheet setting list-style-type to none?  I'm guessing it's one of those two things.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, unfortunately not cross-browser:

```
li
{
    display: inline;
}
li:before
{
    content: '•';
    padding: 0 .5em;
}
```